# Entity Framework Function Import when a Stored Procedure has two Result Sets

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I have a stored procedure that our DBA wrote and I would like to map it to a function import in Entity Framework. This stored procedure returns two result sets. How is this handled in EF? Will I need to make the DBA write two stored procedures, one for each result set? Or is EF capable of handling this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't work out of the box afaik, but have a look at the [ADO.NET Entity Framework Extensions](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions)